# Can a Figure discard something?

Tags: word-usage

I have been criticized for the following usage of *to discard*:

> Figure 7 shows [...]. It is striking to observe that [*surprising fact*]. However, [*tempering the previous fact*]. Thus, Figure 7 clearly discards the possibility that [*impossible hypothesis*].

The comment is "A figure does not discard, it can only visualise something".

It would be easy to reformulate (e.g. "From these observations, we can clearly discard"), but I wonder if this particular usage is correct or not, and if it sounds odd. In the last sentence, I understand "Figure 7" as a shortcut or metonymy of the whole associated reasoning.

Comment: We can understand "discard" as "to get rid of", and there would be no objection. Inanimate and abstract objects can discard **New Concepts of Psychostimulants Induced Neurotoxicity** - Page 245 The current decay was adequately fitted using a single exponential function, which discards the possibility of a fast openchannel blockade mechanism.  ++ **Truth, Rationality, Cognition, and Music** - Page 122
The first assumption discards the possibility that causally inefficacious properties which are in some sense causally relevant figure in causal explanations.

Comment: 'Hypothesis', metonymy and personification are strange bedfellows. I'm surprised your critic passed the figurative (oops) sense of 'visualise'. And the metonymy.

Comment: The person that formulated the critic is not a native speaker. I am not also, but we do not share any other common language than English.
While in French it would be perfectly valid to say "Donc, cela écarte la possibilité que..." (lit. Thus, this - referring to the picture or the whole reasoning around - discards the possibility), in Polish such a construction is totally invalid.

Comment: Too late, but questions about basic English for non-native speakers have their own site: [ell.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that a simple diagram can't discard anything. *Discard* is a verb with a positive **action:** that of [throwing something away](https://www.lexico.com/definition/discard).

A figure or diagram can have an effect, rather than a real action. It can cause you to do something:

> Figure 7 clearly causes us to discard the possibility...

Or it might do something itself which doesn't have a real action, merely an effect:

> Figure 7 clearly invalidates the possibility...

or you might possibly use *show* as that can be metaphorical — that is, if a diagram *shows* something it "causes us to see":

> Figure 7 shows *[impossible hypothesis]* to be impossible.

*Discard* is not [yet!] metaphorical; although English does change, this particular verb still connotes the real action of disposing of something. I believe it's unlikely that *discard* will change its usage: OED shows it in use since 1578 and it's always connoted a positive action (including *displace* or *banish*).

Comment: Very clear and precise. Thank you!

Comment: @Figurative Note that although it's idiomatic (at least informally) to say that *Figure X **shows** [something]*, that's, strictly speaking, also nonsensical. To be precise, it should be *as shown **in** Figure X*. But many people will not quibble over that.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that *discard* is a verb with positive action, it can be argued that a figure can commit the act.

In philosophy and language, a **speech act** is information given by a speaker or writer that not only *expresses ideas*, but *performs an action*. [A Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act) attributes Speech-Act theory to Wittgenstein's philosophical theories.

It is immediately clear that speech act theory talks about speech and writing, but a *figure* may also transmit information, and, by extension, perform actions; an article in [the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/speech-acts/#ConForHowSayMakItSo) holds that "speech acts do not essentially involve language":

> Accordingly, we may now say that speech acts are cases of speaker meaning that can (but need not) be performed by speaker meaning that one is doing so. This conception still counts resigning, promising, asserting and asking as speech acts, while ruling out convincing, insulting and growing six inches. It has the further virtue of ruling out the case of whispering, which one can do without speaker meaning anything and so is no speech act (although of course some speech acts may be performed at the level of a whisper). What is more, speech acts do not essentially involve language: bidding, promising, resigning and challenging are all acts that can be done without words. Our characterization of speech acts captures this fact in emphasizing speaker meaning rather than the uttering of any words.

A common example of this phenomenon "in the wild" is attributing speech to a text, for example: "Whoever believes in me, as Scripture has said, rivers of living water will flow from within them", or "The book makes some extravagant claims that have been put into question." In these examples, a promise is attributed to the Scriptures, and "making extravagant claims" to a book.

In this same sense, a figure can be said to discard an argument.

Comment: Personification is quite common in English, but not in scientific etc registers. The use of 
 'discard' here would be non-standard.